# bitwise operators with an if

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am reading K&R book for c language and in section 2.10 they give the following example:

```
/*bitcount: count 1 bits in x*/
int bitcount(unsigned x)
{
    int b; 
    for(b=0; x!=0;x>>=1)
       if(x&01)
           b++;
     return b;

}
```

The function supposed to count the bits that are 1 in x.

I understand that the if is supposed to "mask off" the bits, but I don't understand how?

Is This condition is basicly:

```
if(x&01==1)?
```

I don't understand this condition.

What does (x&01) mean?

Also, I don't understand when does the loop stop? whenever all the bits have been shifted to right and all the vacated cells are now 0?

I just can't understand how this method works, and I looked for a solution quite a while.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it step-by-step? You could understand the program by examining the values of the variables after each step.

Comment: More precisely, the condition `if (x & 01)` is equivalent to `if ((x & 01) != 0)`, though in practice, the only non-zero value you can get from `(x & 01)` is 1.  In general, `if (expr)` is equivalent to `if ((expr) != 0)`, hence my initial rewrite.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you please explain what does the condition if (x&01) mean? I find it hard to understand. Does it compare x to 0 with & and then x with 1?

Comment: If you need an explanation of bitwise operators, rather than bitwise operators in the context of an `if` statement, you are asking a somewhat different, noticeably larger question.  `01` is an octal constant equal to `001`, `'\001'`, `1`, `0x1`, `0x00000001` etc, aka 'one'.  The bitwise 'and' of two values compares the each bit position in each argument (in `x` and in `1`), and produces a bit in the corresponding result of 1 if both are input bits are 1, and 0 otherwise. In this context, the only bit which can produce a non-zero value is the LSB, least significant bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You understood right about loop termination.

But however an **important note**: This code will work only if `x` is `unsigned`. Because for a signed integer `1` bit is appended as MSB on right shift.

Now `(x & 01 == 1)`:

It basically ANDs the value of `x` to decimal number `1` like this:

x:           0001000100001110 (Some random 32 bit value)
1:           0000000000000001
&
Result:  0000000000000000

Reason for this result:
AND operation does a bit by bit logical AND. You can check the truth table for AND operation on internet.

**A tip/hint for you**: This is **not** the best method to count all the `1` bits in a signed/unsigned number. There exists a method which can count `1` bits in as many loop iterations as there are number of `1`s in the number. Try yourself to implement it or search for that better method.

Answer (score 5):

Let's rewrite the function using a while loop.

```
int bitcount(unsigned x)
{
    int b = 0;
    while (x != 0) {
        if (x & 0x1)
            b++;
        x = x >> 1;
    }

    return b;
}
```

Note that each iteration of the loop, we do two things:

1. If the bottom bit of the number is high (the number is odd), then we add one to our counter of bits.
2. Each iteration, we divide the number by 2 `(x = x >> 1)`.

Comment: is the number hexdecimal? that's the reason you write 0x1?

Comment: @Alan: technically, `01` is octal, `1` is decimal, `0x01` is hexadecimal, but they all have the same value of `1`. I'm just using hex because that's how I think when I deal with shifts. It makes no difference though.

Comment: thank you, but I am asking because you wrote x&0x1 and not x&01. can you please explain what this condition mean? it the most confusing thing here...

Comment: Different number notations only matter to the human reader. Everything to a computer is binary.

Answer (score 3):

> Is This condition is basicly: if(x&01==1)?

Kind of, the condition in other words: if the "x & 01" is non-zero.

> Also, I don't understand when does the loop stop? whenever all the bits have been shifted to right and all the vacated cells are now 0?

When you do x>>=1, you are shifting **all the bits x to the right by 1 step**. If you take a pen and paper, you will also realize that this is same as dividing by 2. When will it stop? When this `x` becomes zero: `x!=0`.

Answer (score 0):

`if(x&01)` means:

for example1: x's binary value is : 1011101
                      01's binary value is: 0000001
                      & is binaryopAND  : ---------
                                       result is : 0000001

for example2: x's binary value is : 1011100 (last bit is 0)
                      01's binary value is: 0000001
                      & is binaryopAND  : ---------
                                       result is : 0000000

so this means `if(x&01)`  :
this condition returns only 2 values "0000001" or "0000000" according to x's last bit value "1" or "0".

`int bitcount(unsigned x)`:
x is defined as unsigned
this means x can be only a positive value.
cuz ungsigned means only positive numbers.
0000000 is NOT POSITIVE NUMBER = NOT UNSINGED NUMBER.

so `b++;` :
since "x" is defined in only postive numbers, x won't accept 0000000 value cuz 0000000 is a not postive number. This will only count values are 0000001.

finally `x >>= 1` :
this will shift x's bits 1 slot to the right-side and will fill the new slot bit that created at the most-left with "0" value.

and `x != 0`:
"for" loop will end when x comes to 0000000 in the end of process of right-side shifting eventually.